# jQuery AJAX request resends after abort on long requests

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have a very large report I have to generate, and I'm using two jQuery AJAX requests to do so. The first sends the command to check the report. The second is a "checkStatus" function that just reports back the status of a flag that I set in the original function.

However, after about a minute, the original request reads "aborted" and the server logs show that a second "getReport" request is started. Firebug doesn't show a second request going out, but there definitely is one coming in. The server is definitely not timing out on the original request, because the report eventually gets generated. Only problem is, if it's a 15 minute report, I have 15 server hungry requests running simultaneously, which eventually crashes our server. Lastly, if I close the browser window that the request is running in, it doesn't result in multiple requests, so it's definitely coming from the browser.

Oh and it works fine on my local host, but dies on the real server, despite identical everything (even the php version).

It's a super weird problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Same in every browser, mac: chrome, safari, FF. Windows: IE 8/9, FF, Chrome

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same issue (long request aborted which is then silently re-sent).

Comment: I never found a solution, but I did find a cause. We were using AWS with a load balancer in front of it. Unfortunately, the AWS load balancers don't have truly adjustable timeouts, and the LB was the source of our problem. Our solution was to build our own load balancer using nginx, which turned out fantastic.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to debug it by doing a positive return on the report without running the report to find where in your code it's failing. This problem could be from any of your JS/Apache/Back-end scripting areas.

If the app works from ajax -> server -> client without doing your report call then something in your report gen code is causing the request to bomb.

Comment: i.e. comment out the actual report generating aspect of it and see if I can get a return? I do. No problem. I don't think it's the report call though - that works fine on a localhost. The Apache back-end has some possibility though. We do use AJAX all over the place, so most of the time the AJAX works fine. It's just on occasion...

Comment: Also, another new development. I added some code that blocks multiple requests from coming through (checks to see if one is running, if so, returns). Report works, but that check status function stops running after some time.

Comment: You may want to think about re-architecting your calls so they're less dependent on each other if that's at all possible. Seems like it's overcomplicated and debugging this might take longer than finding a different solution. Make sure none of your ajax calls are dependent on a system process(i.e. report generation.) Finding a way to use AJAX only for grabbing data already processed might be a better solution than what you're trying to use. Ajax polling is your friend =)

Comment: I think you slightly misunderstand our situation: that is exactly what we're doing. I'm using AJAX to initialize a process that creates a CSV report and emails it to someone. The checkStatus function just polls to see how far along the report is. The issue is that the original call to initialize a process repeats when the ajax call aborts.